# How to get IP address in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

how we get ip address from node.js I'm try many way but it's doesn't work and return ::ffff:127.0.0.1 please give me some advice

This is my code:

```
app.put('/update-user-info', function(req, res){
  // it's doesn't work and return ::ffff:127.0.0.1
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress ||  req.socket.remoteAddress || req.connection.socket.remoteAddress; 
});
```

Comment: use `req.ip`. if you are behind a proxi take a look at: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [GuroKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6570482/gurokung) said, I am going to add one more point to it.

-`Add app.set('trust proxy', true)`

In nginx.conf file:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 10):

Have you try `req.ip`

`req.ip`

> Contains the remote IP address of the request.
>
> When the trust proxy setting does not evaluate to false, the value of
>   this property is derived from the left-most entry in the
>   X-Forwarded-For header. This header can be set by the client or by the
>   proxy.

The req.ip and req.ips values are populated with the list of addresses from X-Forwarded-For

See [Express 4.x API (About req.ip)](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip)

In case you are working with proxy, it requires a special application settings called `trust_proxy` (default is false)

**NOTE**: X-Forwarded-* headers are easily spoofed and the detected IP addresses are unreliable.

See [Options for 'trust proxy' setting](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#trust.proxy.options.table) and [Express behind proxies](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) for more information