# Getting complete ip addrress in express, node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to get complete IP address of the client using express and node.js but what I am getting is ::1. I tried reading this [How to get IP address in node.js express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295635/how-to-get-ip-address-in-node-js-express) not could not find the solution

Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const middleware = (req, _, next) => {
    console.log(req.ip)
    // Here I am getting ::1
    next()
}

app.get("/*",middleware, (req, res) => {
    
    res.send("Hello")
})

app.listen(3000,() => console.log("Server started"))
```

The above code is in the index.js file
Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how how can I get complete ip address?

Comment: Are you running on localhost and connected to your server from localhost?   `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1` (the loopback address).  This is normal.  Connect from a different computer and you should see an actual IP address.

Comment: Yes I am running on localhost and I have connect my server to localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::1`is the IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1` - the loopback address.  That is to be expected if you're connecting to your server from the same computer and using `localhost` as the hostname.

If you connect to your server from a different computer, you should see an actual client IP address.